# Race conditions in io.Pipe?

Tags: go, io, race-condition

I have a function which returns the `Reader` end of an `io.Pipe` and kicks off a go-routine which writes data to the `Writer` end of it, and then closes the pipe.

```
func GetPipeReader() io.ReadCloser {
    r, w := io.Pipe()
    go func() {
        _, err := io.CopyN(w, SomeReaderOfSize(N), N)
        w.CloseWithError(err)
    }()
    return r
}

func main() {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    io.Copy(&buf, GetPipeReader())
    println("got", buf.Len(), "bytes")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/OAijIwmtRr

This seems to always work in my testing, in that I get all the data I wrote. But the [API docs](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe) are a bit worrying to me:

> **func Pipe() (*PipeReader, *PipeWriter)**
>
> *Pipe creates a synchronous in-memory pipe. [...] Reads on one end are
>   matched with writes on the other, [...] there is no internal
>   buffering.*
>
> **func (w *PipeWriter) CloseWithError(err error) error**
>
> *CloseWithError closes the writer; subsequent reads from the read half
>   of the pipe will return no bytes and the error err, or EOF if err is
>   nil.*

What I want to know is, what are the possible race conditions here? Is is plausible that my go-routine will write a bunch of data and then close the pipe before I can read it all?

Do I need to use a channel for some signalling on when to close? What can go wrong, basically.

Comment: The docs mention that "It is safe to call Read and Write in parallel with each other or with Close. Close will complete once pending I/O is done", so I don't see where could a race occur.

Comment: Stop worrying and run the code under the race detector :-). Note that reads and writes are matched: The data you write _is_ been read the moment you write it. Just reads after close drop data. Just make sure that reads actually consume all you want to write.

Comment: The race detector?! Amazing, I didn't realise [there was such a thing](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html). Taking a look now. I'll play with it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no race conditions. As the documentation mentions, reads on one end are matched with writes on the other. So, when `CloseWithError()` is reached, it means every `Write` has successfully completed and been matched with a corresponding `Read` - so the other end must have read everything there was to read.